# C Global Struct

Tags: c

I am using C. I have a Main file, which points to a header file. I'm going to call the former 'Main' and the latter's implementation 'Supplement'. Now when my Main file runs, it calls a function from my Supplement.

That function mallocs and edits a global variable (in my Supplement file.) Moving on, I again call another function from my Supplement file.

Now this is where the problem is, since I'm receiving a Segmentation fault whenever I do that. Using gcc, I was able to find out that during my second function call to my Supplement, the global variable I edited seemingly 'disappears' (print makes it show that it is at 0x0 address and cannot be accessed.)

I'm quite new in C, and I know global variables are bad, but this is an assignment and since we cannot edit the Main file, I can only use a global variable in my supplement file to make it 'remember' my var.

Cut Code:

```
Main:
  // call load
 // check

Supplement:

    typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node* children[27];
}node;

//Root Node
static node* root = NULL;

bool check(const char* word)
{
  //edits word and puts it into input[i](as int)
  for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    { 
       //uses root[input[i]] -this is the problem. Apparently root is 0x0.
    }
}

bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
     //mallocs and edits root. Note that it is quite a handful. Do note that in the context of this function, gdb returns seems to know root. It's just on the check function call that it mysteriously disappears.

//current = root

node* cur = root;
root = malloc(sizeof(node));

//Check if opened
if(dict==NULL)
{
    return false;
}else
{
    int ch = getc(dict);
    while(ch!=EOF)
    {
        //if character is newline
        if(ch==10)
        {
            cur->is_word = true;
            cur = root;
            dSize++;
        }else{
            int value = (ch==APOST)? 26 : ch-ASCII;
            //if there are no nodes yet
            if(cur->children[value]==NULL)
            {
                //make a new node
                node* next = malloc(sizeof(node));
                //point children to node
                cur->children[value]= next;  
                //current becomes new node
                cur= next;
            }else{
            //else, use node
                cur=cur->children[value];
            }
        }
        ch = getc(dict);
    };
    return true;
}

}
```

I am in fact setting the root variable. I am not sure why my code would elicit such a comment.
I am also confirming this by printing root on gdb. The ONLY problem is AFTER load is done, and I'm running check, root is gone.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Could you post a minimal working code sample that shows the problem?

Comment: show the code, better than a narration.

Comment: Could you make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to show us? It's _much_ easier if we can see some code. It might even help you find the problem yourself.

Comment: Many debuggers seem to have problems with static variables. Just for debugging, try to remove the static definition and see if the variable still disappears. Oh, and also show how you do the malloc & edit on root.

Comment: If the `load` function is complete, you don't actually _set_ the `root` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you get an error in your specific case, since you show no code. However, the *proper* way to do this is:

main.c

```
#include "supp.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  set_x (5);
  printf("%d", get_x());
  return 0;
}
```

supp.h

```
#ifndef SUPP_H
#define SUPP_H

void set_x (int n);
int  get_x (void);

#endif /* SUPP_H */
```

supp.c

```
#include "supp.h"

static int x;

void set_x (int n)
{
  x = n;
}

int get_x (void)
{
  return x;
}
```

This code uses a "file scope" static variable inside the c file. You cannot access x directly from any other file. This is called *private encapsulation*, something which is always good programming practice and part of the concept called object-oriented program design.

Comment: Yes, but what's confusing me is that I cannot seem to use the global variable from my file, as when I go to the other function, it seems to 'forget' that I edited the global var.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use a global variable, you can declare the variable in the main()
then give a reference to that variable to the functions that use it

```
bool load(node** root, const char* dictionary);
bool check(node* root, const char* word);

int main()
{
  node* root = NULL;

  load(&root, dictionary);

  ...
  if ( check(node,word) ) 
  {
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot edit the function calls. It seems that this needs a function call edit. Please correct me if I'm wrong.                               PS: I would have never known, unless you had explicitly told me, that the main of another file runs even if it is not the program run! Thanks!